# How to fix my apt-get after updating kernel?

Tags: kernel, software-center

I changed my kernel to 4.8.10 (ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and now, when I try to install softwares, I get abortion, and error messages mentioning the old kernel.
Is there a way to configure the apt-get or any deb package installer so that it can use the current kernel and allow me to install new apps?
thanks,

Re-explaination:
When I try to install with apt-get I get this message:

```
  depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-51-generic: No such file or directory
  run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
  run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
  update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic
  WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic
  Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
  depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic: 

  No such file or directory


  depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory


  depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_otbcX4/lib/modules

  /4.4.0-51-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory


  depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_otbcX4/lib/modules

  /4.4.0-51-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory


  run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-51-generic 

  /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic


  run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 

  4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic


  run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-51-

  generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic


  run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo 4.4.0-51-generic 

  /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic


  Fatal: open /dev/disk/by-id/: Is a directory


  run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo exited with return code 1


  dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic 

  (--remove):


   subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1


  Errors were encountered while processing:


   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic


  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What I see is it is trying to work with my previous kernel and therefore cancels installation.
I need to find a way so that I can fix that problem.
Is that clearer?

Thanks in advance!

uname-a
        Linux raphael-Lenovo-YOGA-300-11IBY 4.8.10-040810-generic
        #201611210531 SMP Mon Nov 21 10:33:06 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
        GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a

```
    lsb_release: error: No arguments are permitted
    lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
    Release:    16.04
    Codename:   xenial
    [1]+  Exit 2                  lsb_release -
```

dpkg-query -l linux-image-* linux-headers-* | grep -e '^i'

```
    ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-45   4.4.0-45.66 all  Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0

    ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic        4.4.0-45.66                  amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

    ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-53                4.4.0-53.74                  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0

    ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic        4.4.0-53.74                  amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

    ii  linux-headers-4.6.4-040604            4.6.4-040604.201607111332    all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.6.4

    ii  linux-headers-4.6.4-040604-generic    4.6.4-040604.201607111332    amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.6.4 on 64 bit x86 SMP

    ii  linux-headers-4.7.0-040700rc3         4.7.0-040700rc3.201606121131 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.7.0

    ii  linux-headers-4.7.0-040700rc3-generic 4.7.0-040700rc3.201606121131 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.7.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

    ii  linux-headers-4.8.10-040810           4.8.10-040810.201611210531   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.8.10

    ii  linux-headers-4.8.10-040810-generic   4.8.10-040810.201611210531   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.10 on 64 bit x86 SMP

    ii  linux-headers-generic                 4.4.0.53.56 amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers

    ii  linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic          4.4.0-45.66 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

    ii  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic          4.4.0-53.74 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP


    ii  linux-image-4.6.4-040604-generic      4.6.4-040604.201607111332    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.6.4 on 64 bit x86 SMP


    ii  linux-image-4.7.0-040700rc3-generic   4.7.0-040700rc3.201606121131 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.7.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

    ii  linux-image-4.8.10-040810-generic     4.8.10-040810.201611210531   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.8.10 on 64 bit x86 SMP

    ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic    4.4.0-45.66                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

    ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic    4.4.0-53.74                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

    ii  linux-image-generic                   4.4.0.53.56                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: You changed your kernel... How? Where did you download and what exact steps did you do to install it? Did you follow any guide? Is there any reason you had in first place to do this? Can you please edit your question and add the actual output you get from running apt?

Comment: Hello,

I installed a new kernel because I had random freezes, with loss of work, and yes I followed a step by step guide of which I lost the adress. steps I remember were: find latest version on a site, then download "image" "standard" "header" and maybe a fourth, which are .deb, install them, and then use Grub to choose the new kernel to boot with.

No more freeze... but impossible to install software.

regards,
Raphael

Comment: What's the output of `lsb_release -a`, `uname -a`, and `dpkg-query -l linux-image-\* linux-headers-\* | grep -e '^i'`?

Comment: I pasted those info on the question above. Thanks for your reply!